# Как передать аудиозапись с RecorderJS к Django?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

Хочу передать запись записанную с микрофона к Django. Но тут появляется проблема в сообщение о:

> CSRF token missing or incorrect

. 
Я понял что это ошибка в processData: false. Когда я ее убираю, все работает. Но когда я убираю processData появляется новая ошибка:

> TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface FormData.

Что мне делать? Как предать Django аудизапись?

```
console.log("Остановка записи")
rec.stop()
gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
$('#btnToStopRecord').attr('id', 'btnToRecord');
$("#toMessage").prop('disabled', false).attr('placeholder', "Введите сообщение...")
rec.exportWAV(function (blob) {
   let data = new FormData()
   data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}')
   data.append('audio', blob)
   console.log(data)
   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: false,
          cache:false,
          url: '{% url 'sendtext' %}',
          data: {
              'audioFile': data,
              'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
          })
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас уже в FormData передан csrf_token. передавайте сразу data: data

```
console.log("Остановка записи")
rec.stop()
gumStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
$('#btnToStopRecord').attr('id', 'btnToRecord');
$("#toMessage").prop('disabled', false).attr('placeholder', "Введите сообщение...")
rec.exportWAV(function (blob) {
   let data = new FormData()
   data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', getCookie('csrftoken'))
   data.append('audio', blob)
   console.log(data)
   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          cache:false,
          url: '{% url 'sendtext' %}',
          data: data, поменять на 
          })
        })
```

и добавить формирование токена csrf

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, чет затупил по поводу передачи data